# Facing "TABLE not found in schema" in debezium / kafka

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, debezium

I am facing following issue while working with debezium and kafka to get data from my oracle database,

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-31603: object "tableName" of type TABLE not found in schema "schemaName"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 6731
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 105
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 2588
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 2827
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 3608
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 5008
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 5336
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 6702
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 9734
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

source debezium is as follows:

```
name=inventory-connector-test13
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector
tasks.max=1
database.server.name=**-*****-**.**.**
database.hostname=***.***.**.**
database.port=1521
database.user=username
database.password=pass
database.dbname=dbname
database.connection.adapter=logminer
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=schema-changes.inventory
table.include.list=schmemaname.tablename
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: +++ This db does not have any pdb.

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake done by my db guy, this error was related to give right privileges to user, after he corrected it the connection was made successfully.